# Calories in a lava crunch cake

Tags: chocolate, calories

From where do the most of the calories in a chocolate lava crunch cake come from? From the crust or the molten chocolate that's inside?

Comment: I know lava cake, in "normal" recipes the answer would be the cake and "lava" would have the same calorie density by weight, the "lava" would have a slightly higher calorie density than the cake by volume. However, I don't know lava "crunch", can you provide a recipe?

Comment: Hmm, I dunno - I was mostly thinking of the Dominos lava crunch cakes which have extremely sweet lava and the outer cake part is not that sweet which gave me the impression that the lava part had most of the calories.

Comment: I don't know Dominos cakes. Traditional "lava cakes" are really just kind of *underdone* so that the center remains liquid, but is made of the same ingredients as the *lava*, which remains liquid because it isn't really *cooked*

Comment: Oh, huh. Why's the cooked part so much less sweet then?

Comment: Sometimes lava cakes are made by baking a lump of ganache into a chocolate cake. This is a slightly more foolproof method: as long as the cake is warm-ish, the center will stay "molten", and there's no chance of it becoming solid via carryover cooking. The ganache would also probably be sweeter than the cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From online comments, this [copycat recipe](http://www.recipemash.com/dessert-pudding-recipes/how-to-cook-american-desserts/how-to-bake-dominos-chocolate-lava-cake/) seems pretty accurate.

So, they're not dissimilar to traditional lava cakes. The soft, flowing "lava" is just batter that isn't cooked. From the copycat recipe:

> Domino’s makes their cakes in the pizza oven. The secret to the gooey center is that the cake is baked at a high temperature to solidify and crisp the outside. Meanwhile, the chocolate lava center stays liquid and gooey. They make for an elegant, yet really easy to make dessert.
>   [image: 1]

So by weight (the leavened cooked batter is lighter), the lava and the cake have the same ingredients, same calories. The "lava" seems sweeter because it is denser, so it has more sugar by volume.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Domino's nutrition guide, the cake includes both "fudge" and "cookie cake". The center is probably the fudge, which is basically a mixture of chocolate, sugar, and fat so that it stays soft as long as it is warm, and would contain much more sugar than the cake.

[Domino's Nutrition Data](http://cache.dominos.com/homev8/docs/menu/dominos_nutrition_v2.21.00.pdf)

Comment: From this (unfortunately somewhat blurry) [picture](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/O-E1bXpu9TI/maxresdefault.jpg), it looks like we may both be right. I can't find a single other picture that shows two distinct types of fillings, but I have seen some that just seem to be too runny to be normal lava cakes. It seems like maybe it's a standard "not done in the middle" lava cake, that's also got additional liquid chocolate stuff. Weird. I may have to order one just to see what the hell it is!